# Is there a reference for ExtendScript action ID codes?

Tags: documentation, listener, extendscript

There is a section called "Appendix A: Event ID Codes" at the end of the [ADOBE PHOTOSHOP CS6 JAVASCRIPT SCRIPTING REFERENCE](http://goo.gl/ukIhf).

Is there something similar but not just for events? For example, I'm using the ScriptListener to learn how to do some selection stuff, and I got code that called `charIDToTypeID( "T   " )` (three spaces after the T).
That's not an event and it can't be found on the reference I linked to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this resource might be of help: http://www.pcpix.com/Photoshop/enum.htm

Answer (score 0):

This is a collection of tools http://ps-scripts.sourceforge.net/xtools.html that will help you dealing with ActionManager, EventCodes...

The Script on http://www.tonton-pixel.com/blog/photoshop-scripting/json-action-toolbox/ "JSON ID Lister" will help you print out all ids of your ps version. Take a closer look at the webside, because there is a lot of usefull stuff.

There are actually two "ID listers" available on http://www.tonton-pixel.com/blog/ :

• http://www.tonton-pixel.com/blog/photoshop-scripting/json-action-toolbox/ "JSON ID Lister" is an automation plugin, for Mac OS X only.

• http://www.tonton-pixel.com/blog/photoshop-scripting/json-sample-scripts/list-internal-ids/ "List Internal IDs" is a platform-independent script written in JavaScript, giving similar results but far slower than the plug-in. Hopefully, you'll just run it once and use its resulting text file later on...